# Creating methods by specifying LinkedHashMaps with generic values as a parameter

Tags: java, linkedhashmap, generic-method

Let's say I have a super class **Car** and my sub classes are **Honda**, **Toyota**, and **Lexus**.

I have 3 LinkedHashMaps using each sub class as the value:

```
LinkedHashMap<String, Honda> hondaModels = new LinkedHashMap<String, Honda>();
LinkedHashMap<String, Toyota> toyotaModels = new LinkedHashMap<String, Toyota>();
LinkedHashMap<String, Lexus> lexusModels = new LinkedHashMap<String, Lexus>();
```

What I am trying to achieve is something like this:

```
public <T> boolean checkModel(LinkedHashMap<String, <T>> lineup, String model) {
    if (lineup.containsKey(model)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Is it possible for me to create a method by specifying LinkedHashMap with a generic value as a parameter so I don't have to repeat the same method for all 3 LinkedHashMaps?

Comment: Side note: Unless there's something peculiar about all Toyotas (and other other brands) that requires its own class, better to just have a `brand` field in `Car` than to have subclasses. Perhaps `InternalCombustionCar`, `HybridCar` and `ElectricCar` may have been better choices? Or even no subclasses, just `Map<String, Car> hondaModels = ...` appropriately populated is what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the thought, it was just meant to be a quick example to illustrate how I can check if a map contains a key, regardless of what the map is, as long as the key is a string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you only want to check if the map contains the key you can use the `?` wildcard.

```
public boolean checkModel(Map<String, ?> lineup, String model) {
    // trim any leading or trailing whitespace for the given vehicle model
    model = model.trim();
    if (lineup.containsKey(model)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now the method will accept any map as long as the key is a string.

If you want to accept only maps that have a string as key and a car as object you can write `Map<String, ? extends Car>` instead. No need to use type parameters.

Comment: thanks this is the solution I was looking for.